# Slope of a quadratic function at its roots.

Tags: functions, slope

I've realised that every quadratic function with two real roots has slope $-1$ and $1$ at its roots. How do you prove that? Why $1/-1$?

For example:
$x^2 - 5x + 6$ has roots = $2$ and $3$.
The derivative  of the function:
$2x - 5$ gives me $1$ and $-1$ when I put $x = 3$ and $2$.

Comment: How about $x^2-1$?

Comment: @Ali Sahad, $\pm 1$ isn't always true. The slope is $\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ for general quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$.

Comment: The simplest counterexample is $x^2$.

Comment: I think you need the condition that the leading coefficient is 0 and the roots differ by 1.

Comment: Even though you're wrong, it's nice that you thought about something. Next time, think about counterexamples instead of thinking about examples that support your theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that in general

$$f(x)=a(x-s)(x-t) \implies f'(x)=a(x-t)+a(x-s)$$

then

$$f'(t)=a(t-s) \quad f'(s)=a(s-t)$$

therefore your claim holds only for special cases but it is true that in general

$$f'(t)=-f'(s)$$

which depends by the symmetry of the quadratic function.

Answer (score 1):

This is not always true as can be see from the examples in the comments.

Consider the quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$, then it has derivative $2ax+b$. So we have $2ax+b=1$ when $x=\frac{1-b}{2a}$ and $2ax+b=-1$ when $x=\frac{-1-b}{2a}$.

Thats is the derivative of the quadratic gives $1$ and $-1$ when the roots of the quadratic are $\frac{1-b}{2a}$ and $\frac{-1-b}{2a}$ respectively.

In your example we have $x^5-5x+6$, where $b=-5$ and $a=1$. Since $\frac{1-b}{2a}=\frac{6}{2}=3$ and $\frac{-1-b}{2a}=\frac{4}{2}=2$ are roots of the quadratic, then it follows that the slope at these points are $1$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically speaking the expression $y=ax^2+bx+c$ is a parabola with a vertical axis.

So it is easy to see that, when the parabola crosses the $x$ axis (zeros are real),  then the tangent lines are symmetrical, and the derivatives antisymmetric as per @user 's answer